# Linked lists. Where to allocate and how to cope with fragmentation?

Tags: c, memory-management

- Location

  - in the heap, fragmented (malloc for every node) -inefficient in several different ways (slow allocation, slow access, memory fragmentation)
  - in the heap, in one large chunk - all the flexibility, gained by the data structure is lost, when needing to realloc
  - in the stack - the stack tends to be rather limited in size, so allocating large structures on it is not recommended at all

Their big advantage, insert O(1), seems rather useless in the environment of fragmented memory and thousands of calls to the memory allocator to give us another 10 bytes.

---

EDIT to clarify:
This question was asked on an interview. It is not a workplace question and so the usual heuristics of hoping to stumble blindly on the correct decision out of a small set of standard algorithms is not applicable.

The existing answers and comments mention that "malloc is not so slow", "malloc partially fights fragmentation". OK, if we use another data structure, for example a C port of the C++ vector (that is - allocate sequential memory of sufficient size, if data expands, reallocate to a twice larger chunk) all problems are solved, but we loose the fast insert/remove. Any scenarios where a linked list (allocated where?) has vast superiority to a vector?

Comment: Most `malloc` implementations already have code to lessen the impact of fragmentation (e.g. they already do allocate larger chunks and give you a piece of that).

Comment: Why do you say insert O(1) has lost its advantage ? The memory allocation operation isn't that expensive even on a fragmented memory.

Comment: @Geek, Alligment, fragmentation, leaks, pointer indirection - so many many drawbacks to a statically allocated list in independent pieces of memory. Only to get a fast insert/remove.

Comment: @Vorac: Have you considered the impact OS paging could have on cache locality, if it performs sensible relocations as it pages to/from secondary storage?

Comment: @Vorac : you seem to be working on a very older architecture OR is the link list hitting millions of nodes ?

Comment: This whole question's horribly naive... using chunks of memory just means you're implementing your own heap routines - moving the problem into your less-experienced hands: only likely to win if you've some special insight into exact size or relative lifetimes of nodes. The meaningful general question here is the old performance trade-offs between vectors and linked lists - of course linked list has vast superiority sometimes... e.g. a Least Recently Used container (for a cache) where just-used nodes constantly need to be moved to the front.  List nodes have stable addresses: another big plus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your linked list implementation, ideally, shouldn't use any of the above. It should be up to the caller to allocate and destroy memory. Think about functions like `sprintf`, `fgets`, etc... Do they allocate any memory? No. There's a reason for that: Simplicity. Imagine if you had to `free` everything you got from `fgets` (or worse yet, `fscanf`). Wouldn't that be painful? Try to develop your functions to be consistent with the standard library.

It might be helpful to declare a `listnode_alloc` function, but this would only wrap `malloc` and a `listnode_init` function. Consider how `realloc` handles `NULL` input...

Comment: Absolutely! But what example memory allocation scheme would you recommend to the caller, in order to facilitate a growing by insertions linked list?

Comment: This depends upon whichever useful problem the program is solving. Perhaps a set of pool handling functions might need to be developed, but they should be independent of the linked list implementation, because this pool handling also applies to situations using other data structures. Furthermore, this optimisation should be made based on heuristics that indicate that the allocation is actually hampering performance significantly (eg. profiling). By developing your linked list implementation so that it doesn't care about allocation/deallocation, you make the optimisation easy to implement later

Comment: @Vorac In short, solve the problem with abstractions that make it easy to implement optimisations at a later date (which happens to be consistent with the standard library design). After you've solved the problem, if you need to optimise your program, do so based on what your profiler says.

Comment: Your comments and **Tony D**'s gave me some insights on the subject. I guess the rest will come with experience. Thank you.

Comment: @Vorac [Here's](http://ideone.com/J7jICJ) an example I wrote a while back, for another question. Think about the abstraction that allows `qsort` to sort any array, and `bsearch` to search any (sorted) array, regardless of type. How would you implement a `list_find_value`? You appear to have thought of cache locality in terms of objects... How might that kind of abstraction improve the cache locality of code?

Answer (score 7):

This sounds like premature optimization. I think the correct way to go about it is to:

1. use the simplest implementation possible;
2. profile the entire program.
3. if profiling shows that there is a performance issue with the list, consider alternative implementations (including alternative allocators).

Answer (score 4):

If you're worried about the standard allocators not handling your specialized 10-byte allocations efficiently, write a custom allocator that grabs a big chunk of memory from the standard (`malloc()`) allocator and doles out small items efficiently.  You should *not* reallocate when you run out of memory in the initial big chunk; you should allocate a new (extra) big chunk and allocate from that.  You get to decide how to handle released memory.  You could simply ignore releases until you release all the big chunks at the end of processing with the lists.  Or you can complicate life by keeping track of freed memory in the big chunks.  This reduces memory usage on the whole, but it is more complex to write initially.

On the other hand, you should be aware of the risk of premature optimization.  Have you measured a performance hit?  Given what I've seen of your recent questions, you should probably stick with using `malloc()` and not try writing your own allocators (yet).

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the exact solution, but another approach

- Handle fragmentation on your own.

  - Allocate big pool of memory
  - For each new node provide memory from this node, until there is free memory.
  - If pool is utilized, allocate another pool and use that to allocate new chunks

However, this is very easier said than done. There will be lot many issues that you may encounter doing this.

So, will suggest to let this kind of optimization to `malloc` and related functions.

Allocation from stack is not a viable option. You can't `malloc` from stack. You will have to pre-allocate big chunk of buffer in some function. In that case, array is better than linked lists.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the memory allocation strategy might varies due to memory fragmentation, thousands of syscalls etc. and this is exactly why O is used! ;-)